# How to prevent debugger from stepping into Object class code in Eclipse when developing with Scala?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, scala, scala-2.10, scala-ide

In my file `file.scala`, I have the following line:

```
  `file.scala`
    > shapes.foreach({ shape =>
     ...
```

When I start to debug it using Eclipse 3.7, scala plug-in version 2.1.0mp3, I press F5 to enter the code. It brings me to the following files in order:

```
  `AbstractFunction1.class`
    > abstract class AbstractFunction1[@specialized(scala.Int, scala.Long, ..
  `Object.class`
      Source code is not found
  `AbstractFunction1.class`
    > abstract class AbstractFunction1[@specialized(scala.Int, scala.Long, ..
  `Function1.class`
    >  trait Function1[@specialized(scala.Int, scala.Long, ...
  `AbstractFunction1.class`
    > abstract class AbstractFunction1[@specialized(scala.Int, scala.Long, ..
  `file.scala`
    > shapes.foreach({ shape =>
  `file.scala`
    > shapes.foreach({ shape =>
```

And then eventually it shows the body of the foreach method with the while loop, not yet entering the one described in `file.scala`.

But I am pressing F5 7 times just to get inside a foreach loop. How can I do better ? Is it possible to specify files to be skipped automatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please [update your Scala IDE to the latest stable release](http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html), i.e., v3.0.0 at the moment of this writing.

Then, you'll be happy to know that the Scala IDE provides a new Scala Debugger that it is specifically tweaked for Scala code. For instance, stepping through a map/foreach/... will work as desired, i.e., you will step inside the closure without being redirected into the classes you mentioned. Have a look at the [Scala Debugger documentation](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/scaladebugger/index.html) for more details and [don't miss the screencast](http://scala-ide.org/docs/videos.html#Part_3__Scala_debugger).

Comment: Awesome! I knew you would do something like that. However, would you know why it does not work for Android scala code?

Comment: Ehm, no idea :-) But drop us a note in the [scala-ide-user ML](https://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user) explaining what's happening and we might be able to help.